# Upload Form Data WIth Bootstrap Modals

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal in my web page which contains a form. I have set the form action and the required inputs like so:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addCategory" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Add Category</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <form action="/add-category" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label>Title</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="Category Title"> <br>

                            <label>Upload Image</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="file" accept="image/*" id="selImg"  onchange="showImage.call(this)">
                            <img src="#" id="imgPreview" style="display: none; height: 100px; width: 100px">

                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>  // save details to form action endpoint, close modal and refresh the page
                </div>
            </div>
```

The problem lies when clicking the save button, this comes with the bootstrap modal. I want to submit the form refresh the page after the button has been clicked. I am using a `node backend`, should I use the `dom` to listen to event clicks on the button, please explain to me.

How can I do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the `<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>` is inside your `<form>` tag and you should be all set. Right now it is not submitting the form and triggering the refresh you desire due to this.

Another solution is to leverage the Bootstrap Modal's events:

```
$('#myModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
  $('#myForm').trigger('submit')
})
```

Comment: That's true. Thanks, a lot